# Pigeonhole Principle for numbers and their divisors within a set

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic, pigeonhole-principle

I am having a hard time thinking about how to cast the below problem into a form that can clearly make use of the Pigeonhole Principle.

Suppose we are given a set $T = \lbrace 1, \cdots, k \rbrace$ for a positive even integer $k$. I would like to show that for any $S \subseteq T$ such that $|S| = \frac{k}{2} + 1$, there exists $x,y \in S$ with $x \neq y$ such that $x$ divides $y$.

The most basic pigeonhole principle basically assumes we have $n+1$ "elements" that we would like to insert into $n$ "boxes" and the principle tells us that we can expect at least 2 elements to be in at least one of the boxes. This principle can be used to prove a lot of things but most examples I have found have pretty obvious "elements" and "boxes", while in this case I am not seeing anything obvious.

It seems at first that one would want to perform $y \mod x$ for each valid pair of $x,y \in S$, but this does not seem smart because then it is not clear what the buckets should be since using $k$ buckets from $0$ to $k-1$ seems not really great when the modulo is done for values that may not be $k$.

Can anyone provide a hint as to how I might approach the problem using this technique?

Comment: Note in particular this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3149790/602049) to the possible duplicate question gives your problem & a simple answer (basically the same as mine which I deleted when I realized your question is basically a duplicate). There are undoubtedly other duplicates of your question, but I can't find them offhand.

Comment: I just found [Using Pigeonhole Principle to prove two numbers in a subset of $[2n]$ divide each other](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/315050/602049) as what is likely a better candidate as a duplicate since the question itself matches this question much more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the boxes to be numbered $1,3,5,...k-1$, where box $i$ contains all numbers of the form $i$ multiplied by a power of $2$.

There are $\frac{k}{2}$ boxes ..... over to you!